# How many functions does it take to solve polynomial equations?

Tags: polynomials, roots

It is well known that polynomial equations of degree $\ge 5$ cannot be solved by just using addition, multiplication, division and radicals  ([Abel–Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)). So what, who cares? Let's just add extra functions until we can solve them! For example, it turns out that polynomial equations of degree 5 can be solved by adding the [Bring Radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) to our arsenal.

> Let $k_n$ be the **minimum** number of univariate, continuous functions that need to be added to `+,-,*,/` in order to solve polynomial equations of degree $n$.

We know that $k_0=0$, $k_1 = 0$, $k_2=1$, $k_3=2$, $k_4=2$, $k_5=4$  (not counting $\sqrt[4]{\cdot} = \sqrt{\sqrt{\cdot}}$)

> Q: Is there *anything* of substance known about the sequence $k_n$ and the associated functions?

I suppose that due to Sprecher's variant of the [Kolmogorov-Arnold Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem) we have an upper bound $k_n\le 2n$ (given a monic polynomials of degree $n$ with coefficients $a_k$ define $\lambda_m(a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}) = $"$m$"-th root and apply the theorem)

So, let's consider a family of functions ${\mathcal F = \{F_n\mid n\in \mathbb N\}}$ with ${F_n\subset C(\mathbb R)}$. Call $\mathcal F$ a minimal family iff:

1. $F_n$ allows us to solve all polynomial equations of degree $n$.
2. $|F_n| = k_n$ for all n

> Q: Do there exist minimal families such that $F_0\subseteq F_1\subseteq F_2 \subseteq F_3 \subseteq \ldots$?

Comment: What about adding the a function $Root(P,a)$ that takes a polynomial and an approximation of a root, and gives the exact value of the root? (This is a well defined function)